# Can I search within the questions I have asked or answered?

Tags: support

Sometimes I want to reference a specific question, but can't find it easily. Of course, I try narrowing down the search terms. Sometimes I have a very important piece of information - I know that I have answered the question - and know that this would filter a lot of the irrelevant results in the search... only if I knew of a way to use it as a search criterium. It used to be easy to manually look over the answered questions in my profile page, but by now, I have 109 answers and growing.

Is there a way to do that, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can search a specific user's posts by their user ID.

For example, to search my posts for "eggs" you'd search for `user:60 eggs`.

Even easier, to search your own posts you can use `user:me eggs`.

These and other search tips can be found on the [search help page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search).